# Mach-O Linker error when trying to setup Google Analytics in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

So I'm trying to get Google Analytics installed inside of my app and have been following the instructions from Google located here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift.

My Podfile looks ike this:

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 platform :ios, '8.0'
 use_frameworks!
 pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
 pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
```

Now everything ran fine after installing pod, but when I added this snippet of code to my AppDelegate.swift file, the app failed to compile.

```
    // Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

   // Optional: configure GAI options.
    var gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
    gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions
    gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose  // remove before app release
```

This is causing the following compile errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo3GAI in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GGLContext", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo10GGLContext in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you ever fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause of your trouble is in the BUILD SETTINGS.  Does your project include ARM64 as the picture below shows?

[image: Xcode Build settings]

Comment: Hi there, yes my architecture is set for arm64

Comment: Do you have a sample project that I look at?  I created the empty project above with your Podfile, and the only part I added as a bridging header file that included the #import <Google/Analytics.h>, but you are not reporting errors related to that.  I also used your CODE snippet for APPDELEGATE.  So, for me things are ok on the build.  I'm using Xcode 6.3.